# lsof - debug the output information

Tags: process, memory, executable, lsof

I was going through the questions of this site. In [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94630/list-all-open-log-files-in-nix) particular question, I see the command lsof being used to list the files that are open for a particular user. I ran the below command in my terminal.

```
lsof -a -u root -d txt
```

I am seeing a long output which are completely irrelevant (at least to me). I am finding it hard to understand the output produced. This is

```
mapping-d  3992 root txt       REG    8,5    29728 7169187 /usr/libexec/mapping-daemon
clock-app  4005 root txt       REG    8,5    88048 7169216 /usr/libexec/clock-applet
mixer_app  4007 root txt       REG    8,5    53484 7169197 /usr/libexec/mixer_applet2
gnome-scr  4078 root txt       REG    8,5   168628 1337742 /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver
notificat  4081 root txt       REG    8,5    34732 1324168 /usr/libexec/notification-daemon
gnome-ter  4219 root txt       REG    8,5   309400 1318348 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
gnome-pty  4221 root txt       REG    8,5    12384 1899888 /usr/lib/vte/gnome-pty-helper
bash       4222 root txt       REG    8,5   735932  196459 /bin/bash
firefox   15551 root txt       REG    8,5   121288 2424613 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
npviewer. 15790 root txt       REG    8,5   174364 1996912 /usr/lib/nspluginwrapper/npviewer.bin
bash      15908 root txt       REG    8,5   735932  196459 /bin/bash
lsof      16014 root txt       REG    8,5   129820 1323233 /usr/sbin/lsof
lsof      16015 root txt       REG    8,5   129820 1323233 /usr/sbin/lsof
```

I was expecting, if I had opened a *txt* file as the *root* user, only that file's information would be displayed, if I run the **lsof** command. Can someone please help me in understanding what this command actually produces as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsof` lists all files that are accessed by a program one way or another. The fourth column (`FD`) describes the way in which the program is accessing the file. Here are some common cases (there are others):

- A number: the file is opened by the process, and the number is the file descriptor. Letters after the file name indicate the opening mode (e.g. `r` for read-only, `w` for write-only, `u` for both).
- `cwd`: the file is the process's current working directory.
- `txt`: the file is the process's executable.
- `mem`: the file is mapped to the process's virtual memory space.

The descriptor type `txt` has nothing to do with “text files” in the sense of containing human-readable text or of having a name ending with `.txt`. Here “text” is an odd bit of terminology refering to executable code, as in the [text segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segment) of an executable file which is the section that contain the code. [This strange name comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282506/where-did-the-text-segment-get-its-name) a now-defunct programming community which predates Unix (General Electric, whose other naming legacy in the Unix world is the “[GECOS field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GECOS#History)”).

Thus what you're seeing is the main executable of each process.

Answer (score 3):

The output is organized into columns. If you want to store this output in a file so that you can review it later simply do this:

```
$ lsof -a -u root -d txt > somefile.txt
```

The columns are right along the top.

```
COMMAND     PID USER  FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
```

#### Description of columns

The columns are as follows:

```
COMMAND     PID USER  FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
mapping-d  3992 root txt       REG    8,5    29728 7169187 /usr/libexec/mapping-daemon
clock-app  4005 root txt       REG    8,5    88048 7169216 /usr/libexec/clock-applet
mixer_app  4007 root txt       REG    8,5    53484 7169197 /usr/libexec/mixer_applet2
```

- **COMMAND** - this is the name of the executable that is using a file.
- **PID** - Process ID, this is the process ID of the executable. You'd see these in the output of the `ps` command as well.
- **USER** - This is the userid that the process is owned by.
- **FD** - File Descriptor. You specified that you only wanted text file descriptors (`-d txt`) so you should only see `txt` in this column. From the man page of `lsof`, "                       txt  program text (code and data);"
- **TYPE** - This denotes the type of node associated with the file. Again consult the man page of `lsof`. There are a lot of different types of nodes. Here we're primarily dealing with regular files, so you'll see the keyword `REG`.
- **DEVICE** - This column contains device numbers. These are the corresponding devices that are being used for the particular file, from the systems `/dev` directory.
- **SIZE/OFF** - size of the file or the file offset in bytes.
- **NODE** - Consult the man page of `lsof`, in general it's either the node number of a local file, or inode number of an NFS file in the server host, but can be other values as well.
- **NAME** - name of file or name of the mount point and file system on which the file resides.